# Postgres uninstall: "server.key has group or world access" error

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, software-installation, postgresql

I'm trying to uninstall postgresql, but its really complaining. I suspect something is broken. I'm on 12.04, installed via apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
```

returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql is not installed, so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of
additional disk space will be used. Setting up postgresql-common
(129ubuntu1) ...  * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server           
* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 2013-07-12 11:13:30 

BST FATAL:  private key file "server.key" has
group or world access 2013-07-12 11:13:30 

BST DETAIL:  File must be
owned by the database user or root, must have no write permission for
"group", and must have no permissions for "other".

invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.1:
postgresql-9.1 depends on postgresql-common (>= 115~); however:
Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Now I have tried to fix the server.key file; I copied the snake oil file to `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/server.key` then I have modded it:

```
chmod 700 server.key
chown postgres:postgres server.key
```

**sanity check:**

```
ls -l server.key

-rwx------ 1 postgres postgres 887 Jul 12 10:07 server.key
```

But it still complains that the file has group access.

Would appreciate any help to remove this, forced reinstall with `install -f` doesn't help. :(

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by purging this package

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-common
```